# How do I limit the GWT modules that are compiled in IntelliJ?

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I've added some extra 'dev' GWT modules into my project. Since I'm using Maven I setup a profile so the Maven build only builds my either my normal module OR my dev module, however IntelliJ is finding all the modules and building them all.

How can I limit which modules IntelliJ sees/compiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click 'File'->'Project Structure' then select 'Modules' and the click on the 'GWT' module on the corresponding pom.xml configuration.

It will let you check and un-check the modules you would like included and excluded respectively.

Comment: Fantastic question and answer.  Worked great for me!